# How to Include a Custom Validator from Another Dependency in WebFlux SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.4 with a typical WebFlux RestController. This endpoint has a custom validator for an enum parameter which is included in the project from an external Maven dependency (not part of the overall project structure that this controller is being housed in), e.g.,

```
@GetMapping("/api/test")
public Mono<MyObject> getObject(@ValidCustom MyEnum myEnum) { ... }

<!-- Inclusion of artifact `module.a` which contains @ValidCustom -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>module.a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The project builds/compiles just fine, however, when the endpoint is invoked at runtime, I get the following:

```
HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint '...ValidCustom' validating type '...MyEnum'. Check configuration for getObject.myEnum
```

Surprisingly, I have another controller that uses the same `@ValidCustom` for its endpoint, and when the handler in that controller gets invoked, the validation works as expected.

The difference is that in the second scenario, `module.a` is part of the overall Maven structure of the application (as opposed to being part of an external module that's being included as part of the dependency).

I have made sure that the package name for `module.a` artifacts is added to `scanBasePackages` list of `@SpringBootApplication` where the first controller is part of.

In the application that I'm having this issue, I can see the jar dependency from module.a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar being included with `ValidCustom.class`.

What is it that I'm doing wrong that causing the validation not being able to find `ValidCustom` in my first application/controller?

[**UPDATE #1**]

I removed `@Validated` from `@RestController` class and now it appears the validation for `@ValidCustom` is working for `MyEnum`.

HOWEVER... other validations such as `@Pattern(...)` or `@NotBlank` are not getting triggered!!!

Why is `@Validated` causes the custom Validators not to get triggered, but its absence does? While its absence causes other validators not to get triggered till it's reinstituted?